# Dynamic calculation formulas in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, formula, named

I'd like to know if there is a possibility to create something like named calculations in Postgres? Say, I have a table:

```
create table foo (
  bar smallint,
  baz smallint
)
```

I can run `select (bar / baz) * 100 from foo;` to get my result, but I'd like to have a formula (pseudocode): `avg_foo ::= (bar/baz)*100` and then do `select avg_foo from foo;` to get the same result. Ideally, I'd like to have a separate table with calculations:

```
create table calculations (
  name varchar,
  formula varchar
)
```

So that I could create calculations dynamically and use them in selects, like this:

```
insert into calculations (name, formula) values
  ('sum_bar_baz', 'bar+baz'),
  ('mult_bar_baz', 'bar*baz');
select sum_bar_baz, mult_bar_baz from foo;
```

How do I do this with Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a tuple returning function in plpgsql, and call the required functions from within.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the answer. Could you be a bit more specific? I'm not sure how to do what you said.

Comment: Learn how to write functions in postgres. Learn how to write plpgsql functions. Read about the EXECUTE statement. It takes a string, parses it, and evaluates it. Use it to create a dynamic query. Learn how to return tuples instead of single values. Read the docs.